# How can I look this email address

Tags: facebook, email, recovery

I'm going to recover my Facebook account but I just forget my email address, can anyone telling me how can I show this full email address. I'm attaching an screenshot please have a looks

Can I show my full email address was

Comment: This is a site for software development questions, not general support for third-party systems. Go talk to Facebook.